# ActiveRecord many_to_many association instantiation returns uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a list of categories in my database (validations not listed for brevity).

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :crimes_categories
  has_many :crimes, through: :crime_categories
end
```

I am seeding my database with crimes, some of which have multiple categories (validations not listed for brevity).

```
class Crime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :crime_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :crime_categories
end
```

These models are joined by a CrimeCategory model

```
class CrimeCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :crime
end
```

The seed file is iterating over a list of crime objects to format and add them to my database. I have tried a few different approaches. The first approach was to create CrimeCategory row.

## seed.rb

```
count = 1
teamCrimeList.each do |crime|
  ...
  categories.each do |cat|
    ...
  end
  category_object = Category.where(name: category)
    crime_category_objects << category_object
    CrimeCategory.create(category_id: category_object.id, crime_id: count)
```

That last line would throw the following error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CrimeCategory
```

Another strategy I tried was the following

## seed.rb

```
teamCrimeList.each do |crime|
  ...
  categories.each do |cat|
    ...
  end
  category_object = Category.where(name: category)
    crime_category_objects << category_object
end
date = Date.parse(crime['Date'])
crime_object = Crime.create(team_id: team.id, date: date, name: crime['Name'], position: crime['Position'], encounter: crime['Encounter'], description: crime['Description'], outcome: crime['Outcome'])
crime_object.categories = crime_category_objects
```

which returns the same error

I also tried this approach

## seed.rb

```
teamCrimeList.each do |crime|
  ...
  categories.each do |cat|
    ...
  end
  category_object = Category.where(name: category)
    crime_category_objects << category_object
end

date = Date.parse(crime['Date'])
Crime.create(team_id: team.id, categories: crime_category_objects.flatten, date: date, name: crime['Name'], position: crime['Position'], encounter: crime['Encounter'], description: crime['Description'], outcome: crime['Outcome'])
```

I threw in some pry's and tried calling `crime.categories`, all of which returns the same error.

I scoured stack overflow and nearly all the entries I came across on this issue have to do with naming errors but insofar as I can tell, there is no naming error.

Comment: Where is CrimeCategory model saved? Rails relies on naming conventions to autoload files. If CrimeCategory is not in `app/models/crime_category.rb` then it will not be autoloaded.

Comment: I was just missing a `_` in my `app/models/crime_category.rb` I instead had `crimecategory.rb`. Thank you!

Comment: It's a semi-common issue. Whenever you get an error like `NameError: uninitialized constant MyClass`, it usually means that your model names do not correspond to the files they are declared in. More in depth [explanation here](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e#model)

Answer (score 0):

@Glyoko had the right idea. I had named my CrimeCategory model file as 
`app/models/crimecategory.rb` instead of `app/models/crime_category.rb`